# What happens to old commits after you use `git commit --amend`?

Tags: git

Suppose we have branch:

`A <-- B <-- C`

Suppose further we use `git commit --amend` to change `C` into `C'`:

`A <-- B <-- C'`

**Question:** What happens to `C` (literally speaking)? Does that commit still exist somewhere in git's object store (it's just dangling from our master branch)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it exists and if you know its sha, you can do

```
git show <SHA>
```

to see it.

It simply remains "orphan" and it's eventually pruned by the garbage collector.

The final situation would be

```
A -- B -- C'
      \
       \-- C (this commit is unreachable, so it's not shown in normal git logs)
```

About the garbage collector, aka [`git gc`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html)

> Runs a number of housekeeping tasks within the current repository, such as compressing file revisions (to reduce disk space and increase performance) and **removing unreachable objects** which may have been created from prior invocations of git add.
>
> Users are encouraged to run this task on a regular basis within each repository to maintain good disk space utilization and good operating performance.
>
> **Some git commands may automatically run git gc**; see the --auto flag below for details. If you know what you’re doing and all you want is to disable this behavior permanently without further considerations, just do:
>
> `git config --global gc.auto 0`

Comment: That last comment seems really important; git will just automatically "garbage collect" without your consent?!

Comment: See my last edit, and in general refer to the `git gc` man page

Answer (score 2):

According to the official documentation, `git commit --amend` is a rewrite of history:

> You need to be careful with this technique because amending changes the SHA-1 of the commit. It’s like a very small rebase – don’t amend your last commit if you’ve already pushed it.

Source: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

So to answer your question:

> What happens to C (literally speaking)?

It still exists, effectively it has been stashed (`git stash`). You could get it back using the process identified here:

http://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-labs/labs/rewinding-git-commit-amend